# Is there a pythonic way to perform REST API calls over a different network namespace?

Tags: python, rest, networking, python-requests, namespaces

I have a REST API server that is available under a different network namespace (tpnns in this example). I can access the server from Linux host as below.

```
ip netns exec tpnns curl --request GET --url http://5.16.100.200:5000/user/Jass
{
    "name": "Jass",
    "occupation": "Web Developer",
    "age": 22
}
```

Is there a way to perform such requests (over a different network namespace than default) when using python requests library?

Comment: does the answer satifies? or need more info?

Answer (score 0):

Well, simplest solution is to write a python script say `try.py` then run it like this:

```
ip netns exec tpnns python try.py
```

Otherwise, there are python modules which allows to run python in a particular network namespace.

Hope this helps.